# dataframe with nested aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have json file which looks like this:

```
{{"name":"jonh", "food":"tomato", "weight": 1},
 {"name":"jonh", "food":"carrot", "weight": 4},
 {"name":"bill", "food":"apple", "weight": 1},
 {"name":"john", "food":"tomato", "weight": 2},
 {"name":"bill", "food":"taco", "weight": 2}},
 {"name":"bill", "food":"taco", "weight": 4}},
```

i need to create new json like this:

```
   {
     {"name":"jonh",
      "buy": [{"tomato": 3},{"carrot": 4}]
     },
     {"name":"bill",
      "buy": [{"apple": 1},{"taco": 6}]
     } 
   }
```

this is my dataFrame

```
val df = Seq(
  ("john", "tomato", 1),
  ("john", "carrot", 4),
  ("bill", "apple", 1),
  ("john", "tomato", 2),
  ("bill", "taco", 2),
  ("bill", "taco", 4)            
).toDF("name", "food", "weight")
```

how can i get dataframe with final structure? **groupBy** and **agg** gives me wrong structure

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("name", "food").agg(sum("weight").as("weight"))
  .groupBy("name").agg(collect_list(struct("food", "weight")).as("acc"))

+----+------------------------+
|name|acc                     |
+----+------------------------+
|john|[[carrot,4], [tomato,3]]|
|bill|[[taco,6], [apple,1]]   |
+----+------------------------+

{"name":"john","acc":[{"food":"carrot","weight":4},{"food":"tomato","weight":3}]}
{"name":"bill","acc":[{"food":"taco","weight":6},{"food":"apple","weight":1}]}
```

please give me right direction how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always convert the values manually, by iterating over `Row`s, and assembling the `food`-`weight` pairs, and then converting them to a `Map`

```
val step1 = df.groupBy("name", "food").agg(sum("weight").as("weight")).
    groupBy("name").agg(collect_list(struct("food", "weight")).as("buy"))
val result = step1.map(row =>
    (row.getAs[String]("name"), row.getAs[Seq[Row]]("buy").map(map =>
        map.getAs[String]("food") -> map.getAs[Long]("weight")).toMap)
    ).toDF("name", "buy")
result.toJSON.show(false)

+---------------------------------------------+
|{"name":"john","buy":{"carrot":4,"tomato":3}}|
|{"name":"bill","buy":{"taco":6,"apple":1}}   |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Looks great. I thought about map, but didn’t really understood how exactly. I will check and update. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achive your *required json format* by using *replace techniques*

**udf way**

`udf` function works on *primitive data types* so `replace` function can be used to replace the `food` and `weight` string from final `dataframe` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def replaeUdf = udf((json: String) => json.replace("\"food\":", "").replace("\"weight\":", ""))

val temp = df.groupBy("name", "food").agg(sum("weight").as("weight"))
  .groupBy("name").agg(collect_list(struct(col("food"), col("weight"))).as("buy"))
  .toJSON.withColumn("value", replaeUdf(col("value")))
```

You should have output `dataframe` as

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|value                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|{"name":"john","buy":[{"carrot",4},{"tomato",3}]}|
|{"name":"bill","buy":[{"taco",6},{"apple",1}]}   |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

**regex_replace function**

`regex_replace` *inbuilt function* can be used to get the desired output as well

```
val temp = df.groupBy("name", "food").agg(sum("weight").as("weight"))
  .groupBy("name").agg(collect_list(struct(col("food"), col("weight"))).as("buy"))
  .toJSON.withColumn("value", regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col("value"), "\"food\":", ""), "\"weight\":", ""))
```